# ReferenceError: privateKey is not defined

Tags: node.js, cryptography, sign

**Veryfing Keys**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

var privatekey = req.body.publickeytext;
var publickey = req.body.publickeytext;

const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
sign.update('some data to sign');
sign.end();
const signature = sign.sign(privateKey);
console.log("signature");
console.log(signature);

const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
verify.update('some data to sign');
verify.end();
const veritifation = verify.verify(publicKey, signature);
```

[image: I need to get the private key from a from in HTML frontend]

**The keys are generated:**

```
 const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
                        modulusLength: 4096,
                        publicKeyEncoding: {
                          type: 'spki',
                          format: 'pem'
                        },
                        privateKeyEncoding: {
                          type: 'pkcs8',
                          format: 'pem'
                        }
                      });
```

**ERROR**

> privateKey is not defined
>   ReferenceError: privateKey is not defined

**TOOLS**
I am using node JS, crypto, express. Thank for your help

Comment: You've set the variables (identifiers) `privatekey publickey` but you're trying to use `privateKey publicKey`. These are different. Pick _one_ set of names and use them consistently.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Worse: `var privatekey = req.body.publickeytext;` ... oh dear.